# Help with the following derivative 8

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, economics

Is there anyone who can help me with the following derivative? I have the following equation, Which I must derive with respect to h:

$$u^{*}=\frac{\alpha +\tau h+\omega \dot{y}+\psi e^{r}(h)}{\left [ s_{w}+(s_{\pi }-s_{w})h\frac{1}{v}\right ]-\beta +\phi}$$

Obtaining the following result:

$$\frac{\partial u^{*}}{\partial h}=\frac{ \tau - s_{w}+(s_{\pi }-s_{w})h\frac{u}{v}+\psi \frac{\partial e^{r}}{\partial h}}{\left [ s_{w}+(s_{\pi }-s_{w})h\frac{1}{v}\right ]-\beta +\phi}$$

Thanks to anyone who will help me.

Comment: Which are the variables and which are the constants?  What have you done so far?

Comment: All constant except h, it's a partial derivation. However can't figure out how the elevation power 2 of the denominator can disappear. Thank u :)

Comment: If the only variable is $h$ how can this be a partial derivative?  Or why does the term ${\partial e^r\over\partial h}$ appear?  What is $\dot{y}$ is it's not a derivative?  What does the $u$ on the right-hand side in the second formula mean?

Comment: The term ∂er/∂h appear because e is a non-specified function of h. Y with dot is a growth rate, not a derivative. Can't understand why there is a u at the right-hand side too.